# Document ID retrieval

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

this is supposed to take the user ID from the result!.user.uid and store it a variable or function in order for me to use it again.
the problem is that I dont know how to get it to store the value outside of this function.
Ive tried to make it store to a variable outside of the initial button function, and Ive also tried to return it outside of the function by removing a part of the code which made it become a void. Im not sure where i need to go/what else I can try and do in order to fix this problem.
If anybody know how do I retrieve my document ID from this code your help would be greaty appreciated

```
@IBAction func NextButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    //validate the fileds
    let Error = validateFields()

    if Error != nil {        
        // there is somthing wrong with the fields show error message
        showError(Error!)        
    }
    else {

        // create cleaned versions of the data
        let Password = PasswordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let Email = EmailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let Firstname = FirstnameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let Lastname = LastnameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let Age = AgeTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

        // create the user
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: Email, password: Password) { (results, Err) in

            // check for errors
            if Err != nil {
                // there was an error creating the user
                self.showError("Error creating user")               
            }
            else {
                // user was created succesfully store first and last name
                let db = Firestore.firestore()

                db.collection("users").document(results!.user.uid).setData(["first name":Firstname, "last name":Lastname, "age":Age,  "uid":results!.user.uid]) { (Error) in

                    if Error != nil {
                        // show error message
                        self.showError("error saving user data")

                    }
                    //showing users document id 
                }

                //transition to the home screen
                self.transitionToHome()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea what to do any help would be amazing,

thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Define a uid variable outside of the IBAction function like so.

```
var uid: String? = nil
```

Then, within the createUser function

```
self.uid = results!.user.uid
```

Comment: Thank you Sanzio, what if I then want to access this uid from a diffrent view controller, how do I make it so the other view controller doesn't say "Use of unresolved identifier"

Comment: Theres a lot of ways to do this depending on how you have your view controller stack set up. Could you provide more context? For example, is this within a UINavigationViewController, etc. It's not a straightforward answer as there are nearly infinite ways to do this. I would recommend you become familiar with the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers. Don't just know how to type the code, but understand.